# sql with multiple counts against one child table

Tags: sql, db2

DB2 database. A Request can have multiple Transactions. I'd like to query the request and get a count of different transaction types. So request 1 with four transactions (AA, BB, BB, CC) would result:
REQ=1234, REQ_USER='Susan', REQ_ACCT=223344, CNT_AA=1, CNT_BB=2, CNT_CC=3

This query gets me an accurate count of one transaction type:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TRANS_AA
FROM TABLE1 AS T1, TABLE2 AS T2
WHERE T1.REQUEST_ID=1234 
AND T1.COMPONENTID = T2.PARENTCOMPID
AND T2.TRANS_TYPE='AA';
```

If I also want the request id, this query gives me that but I need to 'Group By' request id:

```
SELECT T1.REQUEST_ID, COUNT(*) AS TRANS_AA
FROM TABLE1 AS T1, TABLE2 AS T2
WHERE T1.REQUEST_ID=1234 
AND T1.COMPONENTID = T2.PARENTCOMPID
AND T2.TRANS_TYPE='AA'
GROUP BY T1.REQUEST_ID;
```

I'm not sure how to add several columns from T1 (user, account, etc) and several counts of transaction types (let's say we have 10 different types). I've tried some INNER JOINs between the two, but am not sure if this can be done efficiently, or one JOIN for all counts, or multiple joins, etc.

I posted a sample of the data I'd like to get back, but per request below.

```
TABLE1
componentid (key)
request_id
req_user
req_account
... 27 more columns

TABLE 2 (child table, could have many trans_types for T1)
parentcompid (foreign key to componentid in Table1)
trans_type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WINDOW functions of DB2 to achieve this.

You can rewrite your existing query as:

```
SELECT T1.REQUEST_ID, COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY T1.REQUEST_ID) AS TRANS_ABC 
  FROM TABLE1 AS T1, TABLE2 AS T2 
 WHERE T1.REQUEST_ID=1234  
   AND T1.COMPONENTID = T2.PARENTCOMPID 
     AND T2.TRANS_TYPE='ABC'
```

You can use any column in the select list when you use a window function.
Check the link below for more information:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0023461.htm

If you wanted the data to be pivoted am not sure if DB2 inherently supports PIVOT/UNPIVOT.
This is the best I can construct (not sure about performance though and haven't testedt the query):

NOTE: This query considers 6 different types of trans_types. If the Trans_Type is not finite then am not sure if there would be any easy solution.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
                SELECT  t1.request_id, 
                                t1.req_user, 
                                t1.req_acct, 
                                SUM(DECODE(trans_type, 'AA',1, 0)) OVER(PARTITION BY t1.request_id) AS trans_aa, 
                                SUM(DECODE(trans_type, 'BB',1, 0)) OVER(PARTITION BY t1.request_id) AS trans_bb, 
                                SUM(DECODE(trans_type, 'CC',1, 0)) OVER(PARTITION BY t1.request_id) AS trans_cc, 
                                SUM(DECODE(trans_type, 'DD',1, 0)) OVER(PARTITION BY t1.request_id) AS trans_dd, 
                                SUM(DECODE(trans_type, 'EE',1, 0)) OVER(PARTITION BY t1.request_id) AS trans_ee, 
                                SUM(DECODE(trans_type, 'FF',1, 0)) OVER(PARTITION BY t1.request_id) AS trans_ff,
                                        SUM(1) AS total_trans
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1.request_id) AS rn
                FROM TABLE1 AS t1, TABLE2 AS t2
                WHERE t1.request_id=1234 AND t1.componentid = t2.parentcompid
            ) a
 WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: But how do I do this to query one column for counts of different values? I'm looking for somthing like the following: REQ=1234, REQ_USER='Susan', REQ_ACCT=223344, CNT_AA=1, CNT_BB=2, CNT_CC=3

Comment: added table format above. Really I'll get all requests for 'today'. Right now, I'm just trying, for a given request_id, to get one row back which contains column from the request, then columns which represent totals of the different types of transactions (which come from a set of 9 different possible values, like 'AA', 'BB', 'CC'...)

Comment: I understood what you want... it needs PIVOT/UNPIVOT Operations...Let me work on the query and get back to u

Comment: Are tht Transaction Types finite?

Comment: This is very close, thank you much. The Trans_types are finite, about 9 potential values, so this will work. One problem, one question. 

PROBLEM: In the case I have 4 Trans entries, I get 4 lines back. Each line is identical, and has the correct totals. How do I get just one returned line?

QUESTION: I'd like one more column with a TOTAL count of all transactions, regardless of value. I tried adding a 'DECODE' line using '*' as a value, but it returned zero. Using the sample data above, AA=1, BB=2, CC=1, TOTAL=4.

Comment: So I need to group by every column from Table1? I plan on selecting 30 columns from that table. I tried it, and got the following error:
SQL0119N  An expression starting with "trans_type" specified in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause is not specified in the GROUP BY clause or it is in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause with a column function and no GROUP BY clause is specified.  SQLSTATE=42803

Comment: Give it one more try... I had to use ROW_NUMBER WINDOW function (because you need to select 30 cols and grouping by cols is much worse)... Again am not sure about the performance of this query..

Comment: That is very nice! Amazing. I think I have everything I need but one: I'd like one more column with a TOTAL count of all transactions, regardless of value. I tried adding a 'SUM(DECODE)' line using '*' as a value, but it returned zero. Using the sample data above, AA=1, BB=2, CC=1, TOTAL=4. Possible? This query will execute via nightly batch, to pull all requests for a given date (instead of req_id=? we will use req_date=?), so I'm not terribly concerned about performance.

Comment: similar error for whatever column is before - I double-checked and tried various commas and order: SQL0119N  An expression starting with "trans_type" specified in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause is not specified in the GROUP BY clause or it is in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause with a column function and no GROUP BY clause is specified.  SQLSTATE=42803

Comment: Final note: SUM(1) did the trick, I looked at the wrong column (rn). Thanks again for your tremendous help, Cybernate!